# UIActivityViewController with ugly header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I use a UIActivityViewController with valid activities in the activityItems (NSArray).

```
UIActivityViewController* activityController=[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have a problem with the appearance of the UIActivityViewController both in the simulator and on the iPhone itself. If I click 'Mail' then a mail form pops up that displays its title 'New message' directly over the statusbar (can't show you a picture 'cause I lack 'reputation'?) ending up with text written over info in the status bar.

The same happens with the message-activity. I think that the things I do are pretty basic and don't even offer the opportunity to mess things up. So what can be the reason that this happens? Or better: how can I prevent this from happening?

([Screenshot of the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ze6ak1rpdmheco5/title.tiff).)

Comment: I need an image ... if you can't post it then add a link to it

Comment: Here's the image: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ze6ak1rpdmheco5/title.tiff)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution what worked for me is to embed view in Navigation Controller.

If you are using Storyboard you can try this.

Comment: That is not a solution for this situation. It might be a workaround (which it is not - I tried), but it is not the answer. The view controller in which the UIActivityViewController is presented is a UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>. Nowhere in Apple's documentation or anywhere online I am warned not to do this. So, although it is a real problem I have here and I really liked it solved, I am also interested in the 'academic' aspects of this particular problem.